# Could not get audio input for record source 7 on quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using Quickblox  version 2.5.2 to develop video chat. But when ever the call connects its crashing. I have added the log files below.

```
E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 7, sample rate 48000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, session 648, flags 0
E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22. E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
W/System.err: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected condition to be true
W/System.err: at org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioRecord.assertTrue(WebRtcAudioRecord.java:266)
W/System.err: at org.webrtc.voiceengine.WebRtcAudioRecord.InitRecording(WebRtcAudioRecord.java:186)
E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/jvm_android.cc, line 117
# Check failed: !jni_->ExceptionCheck()
# Error during CallIntMethod
#
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13555 (Thread-2350)
```

I googled to solve this issue, but I didn't get any relevant answer.